# Print netcat input on terminal

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, netcat, nc

I'm trying to write a script where I cat the content of a file and pipe it into `nc`:

```
$cat somefile.txt | nc server port
```

The file content is sent to the server as expected but on the terminal I only see the response of the server.

What do I need to do such that I also see what I've sent.

I get a different response for every line from somefile.txt and i would like to have everything together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee` and take advantage of process substitution:

```
$ cat somefile.txt | tee >(nc server port)
```

`tee` simply copies its *input* to both `stdout` **and** a file.

With `<()` (`bash` process substitution) you're telling `bash` to write to the input of a command instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` and avoid process substitution:

```
$ ( cat somefile.txt | tee /dev/fd/3 | nc host port ) 3>&1
```

The benefit of this is that `nc` will run synchronously. Here's an example of async process substitution behavior:

```
user@hostname $ cat somefile.txt
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: StackOverflow.com

user@hostname $ cat somefile.txt | tee >(nc stackoverflow.com 80); echo "DONE"
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: StackOverflow.com

DONE
user@hostname $ HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
[...]
```

Notice that it says "DONE" and draws a prompt in the middle of the output. This is not an issue if `nc` runs synchronously:

```
user@hostname $ ( cat somefile.txt | tee /dev/fd/3 | nc stackoverflow.com 80 ) 3>&1; echo "DONE"
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: StackOverflow.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
[...]
DONE
```